# Private sd storage

Tags: android

I have an app which takes pictures and saves them to sd, problem is that picture modification (delete,rename,ecc.) should be done just throught the app so I need a way to make the pictures folder not accessible to user...is it possible?

Comment: own algorithms are usually crappy unless you are experienced in crypto field. There're lot of solid, proven algorithms to choose from. Do not reinvent the wheel. Square wheels are usually of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the common Android architecture the SD-Card is formatted using FAT32 filesystem. As FAT32 does not support any access control mechanisms you can not rely on that.

Therefore the only possibility is encryption. Create an encryption key and store in the private app data folder. Then use it for encrypting the privacy sensitive files you want to store on the SD-card.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to encrypt the files that you store. There is no way to prevent users mount the sdcard to access every file stored in it.